# Associate Record to Nearest Manager

Tags: sql, presto

I have a table (t_budget) that lists the IDs of employees who are responsible for a given budget along with the allocated amount & spend against budget. This table is the result of a larger query that first targets HR data to get list of budget owners and then joins to the spend table (on budget_owner = employee_id) to import spend. The issue is that some spend is from employees who are not budget owners. In this case, I need to map the spend to the nearest budget_owner  for the employee.

Output table before matching spend to nearest employee. The goal is for the 2nd row (Budget_Owner = 10) to show the spend from Employee 8 ($200) since this budget owner is the closest person accountable for spend.

```
+--------------+------------------+-------+
| Budget_Owner | Allocated_Budget | Spend |
+--------------+------------------+-------+
| 1            | 500              | $100  |
+--------------+------------------+-------+
| 10           | 600              | $0    |  '<--- $200 
+--------------+------------------+-------+
```

---

The second table (t_spend) has employee_id, spend, and a string in format `id1/id2/..../idn` (ID_Path_Up) This field follows the IDs of the manager chain from the employee to the owner *(me, manager, skip manager, ..... , CEO ID)*. Since 'ID = 8' (second row) is not a budget owner, the spend needs to be assigned to the nearest id in `ID_Path_Up` that is present in t_budget.

```
+-------------+-------+-------------+
| Employee_ID | Spend | ID_Path_Up  |
+-------------+-------+-------------+
| 1           | 100   | 1/2/3/4/5/6 |
+-------------+-------+-------------+
| 8           | 200   | 8/9/10/11   |
+-------------+-------+-------------+
```

---

If any other tool I would use a loop but I'm not sure if that can be done in SQL. How can I determine the first 'id' match from a string to a list to?

Answer (score 0):

Create a function with the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_ParseDelimitedList] (@parseChar char(1), @strString varchar(4000))

RETURNS  @Result TABLE(Value int)
AS
BEGIN
 
      DECLARE @x XML 
      SELECT @x = CAST('<A>'+ REPLACE(REPLACE(@strString, ' ', ''),@parseChar,'</A><A>')+ '</A>' AS XML)
     
      INSERT INTO @Result            
      SELECT distinct t.value('.', 'int') AS inVal
      FROM @x.nodes('/A') AS x(t)

    RETURN
END
```

Then, in your query, do something like this:

```
SELECT t2.[Employee_ID], t3.[Budget_Owner], t2.[Spend] FROM spend_table t2
LEFT JOIN budget_table t1 on t2.[Employee_ID] = t1.[Budget_Owner]
JOIN budget_table t3 on t3.[Budget_Owner] in (select * from [fn_ParseDelimitedList]('/', t2.[ID_Path_Up]))
```

This way, you could also add some stuff to aggregate and roll-up if you want.